# How to search in array and show in ListView?

Tags: java, android, regex, listview

following is my Java code in Android Studio. GUI Layout contain an editText where a word is to be input and then click on search button. After that, it will show the matching words from an array (which contain words) and display those in a listView. The functionality of fetching matching regex from array and then displaying item by item in listView is to be implemented; I need idea about that how to implement it in Finder function.

Example 1:

Array of Words : "Dust", "Duff", "Thrust", "Man", "Grade", "Mole", "Tax"

Input: ust

Output in listView:

Item 1: Dust

Item 2: Thrust

```
package com.neatsoft.hamqafia;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText textBar;
    Button findBtn;
    ListView listView;





   String words[] = {"Dust", "Duff", "Thrust", "Man", "Grade", "Mole", "Tax"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private void Init(){
        textBar = (EditText)   findViewById(R.id.editText);
        findBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    }

    private void Finder(String toFind){
        //Store Array in Trie Datastructure and then find toFind keyword and show the results item by item in listView
          ///OR create regex search by any other datastructure or methodology
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when clicked the search button .you can search text in list items with String str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase()) and  save strings that contains search key in another list or array .after that reload data to listview with search list items .

note : you can use another button (clear search) and when click it, assign searchlist variable to initial list  and reload data .(no search case)

```
private void Finder(String toFind){

    if(searchList == null) {
        searchList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    searchList.clear();

    if(toFind != null || !toFind.trim().equals("")) {
        for(String str : words) {
            if(str.toLowerCase().contains(toFind.toLowerCase()))
                searchList.add(str);
        }
    }
    notifyDataToListView();
}

private void notifyDataToListView() {
    if(adapter == null) {
        adapter = new BaseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return searchList == null ? 0 : searchList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                if(convertView == null) {
                    convertView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                }
                ((TextView) convertView).setText(searchList.get(position));
                return null;
            }
        };
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }else {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

like this.Define a BaseAdapter object globally.

Comment: any example to explain it please

Comment: it is enough for you?